# While loop ends prematurely on a regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am running the following Perl script via ActivePerl to extract the time and ID numerical values from a text. 
For some reason, the while loop ends after the first line of the text is checked.

Here is the Perl code I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$inputfile = "nr_raw.txt";
$outputfile = "results.txt";  #create this output file (it will be created automatically in the current folder)
open (OUTPUTFILEHANDLE, "> $outputfile") || die "I can't find or open $file: error $!\n";
open (INPUTFILEHANDLE, $inputfile) || die "I can't find or open $file!\n";
$_=<INPUTFILEHANDLE>;
while (/{.*?"timestamp":(\d+).*?"accountId":(\d+).*?}\n/sg)
{
$info="timestamp: $1 accountID: $2";
print "$info \n";
print OUTPUTFILEHANDLE $info ;
}
close OUTPUTFILEHANDLE;
```

`nr_raw.txt`: (No `accountId` entry on third line)

```
{"eventType":"alarm","timestamp":1508845227478,...,"accountId":1275676,"Version":"1.3",....}
{"eventType":"alarm","timestamp":1508845166740,...,"accountId":1274721,"Version":"1.1",....}
{"eventType":"alarm","timestamp":1508845187479,....,..................,"Version":"1.1",....}
{"eventType":"alarm","timestamp":1508845166980,...,"accountId":1347376,"Version":"1.2",....}
```

`results.txt`: (Nothing else)

```
timestamp 1508845227478 account ID1275676
```

Comment: It's been 23 years since the release of perl 5.0. You're allowed to `use strict;` and `use warnings;` now.

Comment: Your code only reads one line from the file.

Comment: $_=<INPUTFILEHANDLE>; #  Just read the first line from file

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the clarification. I used a similar script on other text file but in that case it worked probably because the entire text was probably one line (no LF/CR)

Answer (score 3):

You only ever read one line!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );

my $parser = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new();

while (<>) {
    my $rec = $parser->decode($_);
    print("timestamp: $rec->{timestamp} accountID: $rec->{accountId}\n")
        if $rec->{accountId};
}
```

Usage:

```
script nr_raw.txt >results.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I will install the Cpanel::JSON::XS module ant use it!

Answer (score 0):

Put the regex in an if statement and make the while loop read every line.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use autodie; # See http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html

    my $inputfile = "nr_raw.txt";
    my $outputfile = "results.txt";  #create this output file (it will be created automatically in the current folder)

    # autodie handles errors automatically.
    open my $out_fh, '>', $outputfile;
    open my $in_fh, '<', $inputfile;

    while( my $line = <$in_fh> ){
        if( $line =~ /{.*?"timestamp":(\d+).*?"accountId":(\d+).*?}\n/sg ){
            my $info = "timestamp: $1 accountID: $2";

            print "$info \n";
            print $out_fh $info ;
        }
    }

# autodie handles errors automatically.
close $out_fh;
close $in_fh;
```

Comment: I works as a charm, thank you. Now I realize it is exactly what I was supposed to do. I I was confused because the same script worked on other text files (probably because they were just one lin, no LF/CR). Thank you again!